# Validation of regex input through json schema

Tags: json, regex, jsonschema

I have to accept a `regular expression` as an input from user  from html page. I am using spring boot for backend with json schema validation

`Pattern.compile(regex);`

method in java as backend, will throw an error if it is not valid regex. This will not throw any error if it is a valid regex.

Can we do the same thing with json schema for validating regex input without using dynamic method in java?(So that number of test cases can be reduced)

How can we acheive this with just json schema?

Comment: {"regexInput":"[]"} is invalid

Comment: {"regexInput":"[A-Z]" is a valid json

Comment: Yes, you use a regex. You'll have to work out what regex you need to validate a regex. Look at the `pattern` JSON Schema keyword.

Comment: I was wondering what regex I can  use validate a regex which will be passed as string

Comment: Can you write some examples out here so that things will be clear what exaclty you want to do ?

Comment: Whenever we give a regex to Pattern.compile(regex), it will throw PatternSyntaxException if pattern is not valid in java. eg., "[a-z" is not valid, "[a-z]" is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Validation of regex input through json schema**

To accept/validate a request body containing a input field for regex. Normally we have to use **Pattern.compile(myRegex)** where myRegex is input filed for regex. If it throws error (e.g,PatternSyntaxException In java), it is invalid otherwise it is valid regex.

---

This can be done in json schema also

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "This is for validating input json request body containing myRegex field which accepts regex",
  "required": [
    "myRegex"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "myRegex": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "regex"
    }
  }
}
```

This schema validates this below request bodies of POST/PUT

---

```
{

    "myRegex":"*8"
}
```

The above request body is  invalid as "*8" is not a valid regex

---

```
{

    "myRegex":"^[_A-Za-z0-9][-_A-Za-z0-9.]*$"
}
```

This is valid according to schema

---

Reference:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#format

The "regex" attribute has been newly introduced in draft 7